# Control systems composed of several different parts just as program blocks

Tags: assembly, compiler

We're having a course on System Software this semester and we're covering the chapter on Assemblers presently. Our professor gave us some questions to think about. One of them is this:

> Control systems maybe composed of several different parts just as program blocks. Is this good or bad for the assembler? If this creates a problem, how can it be solved?

I find this a bit weird. Presumably, control systems can indeed be written in terms of "program blocks" but I'm not sure whether anything can be said about its suitability (good or bad) for the assembler. Can someone provide some hints on this question?

Comment: I think by "program blocks" he means modularity, many functions that each do a small task, in general not only applied to control systems.

Comment: I guess the _worst_ thing the assembler could do is not optimize all those functions and increase the latency in the control loop (if you have to take a lot of jumps and reload the cache/registers), but still, there is only so much people should rely on an assembler _implicitly_ having to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor might like to have you think about the necessity of a *linker*. Since we don't know the stuff you already learned, it is hard to tell.

If you divide the source code of a whole application into parts, these parts need to call functions (subroutines) in other parts or access variables of other parts. Since you will translate each part separately, *what problems might arise, if any at all*?

Structuring an application with modules has several advantages; you will learn about them during your lessons.